# Integers with NA in pandas from json_normalize

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, na

I do `df = pandas.io.json.json_normalize(data)` and I want to specify datatype of an integer column that has missing data. Since pandas doesn't have an integer NaN, I want to use dtype `object`, i.e. string. As far as I can tell, `json_normalize` doesn't have any `dtype` parameter. If I try to `.astype(object)` the columns afterwards, I'll end up with decimal points in the column.

How can I get the string format with no decimal point into this column?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a more elegant solution, but this one should work for your specific task:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(object).apply(lambda x: '%.f' % x)
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps also `df.col.astype(object).apply('{:.0f}'.format).str.replace('nan', '')`

Comment: @Hatshepsut Yeah, that's way better!